# How to write this kind of a query in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
    a_count        b_count          total_count(a_count+b_count)
    2                 3              
    5                 1
    4                 7
    5                 0
```

This is my table I need to update total count field using a single query. How can I write that kind of a query?
I need output like this

```
    a_count        b_count          total_count(a_count+b_count)
    2                 3                   5
    5                 1                   6
    4                 7                   11
    5                 0                   5
```

Comment: This is a very trivial UPDATE query. What have you tried so far? :)

Comment: I need a query like this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To update the values of those fields in the table:

```
UPDATE mytable SET total_count = a_count + b_count
```

To get those fields from the table:

```
SELECT a_count, b_count, total_count FROM mytable
```

To get those fields without that total_count column:

```
SELECT a_count, b_count, (a_count+b_count) AS total_count FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also write a trigger for that

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `total_count` BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE on `table`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET NEW.total = NEW.a+NEW.b;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```